# SSRS Textbox Only Displays Partial Data

Tags: reporting-services, epicorerp

I have a report in SSRS that contains many textboxes that pull data from our Epicor 10 database. One in particular only displays the first 30 characters. In our ERP system, the field format is x(16000) so the user can enter quite a bit of data. The textbox size is definitely large enough to contain more than 30 characters (it's about half a page wide). I enabled the "Can Grow" option, and I've expanded the text box box horizontally and vertically, but still, only the first 30 characters display.

Typically, the text in this field begins with a number (these are shipping comments so it will say, for example, "2 Skids @60 boxes... etc.). That's the only real difference I can find between this particular text box and the other ones on the report that display the entire field value. Am I missing some Option, or do I need to convert the field in some way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to check if the problem is really related to SSRS, query the database from SSMS and check how many characters that column returns. Also remember the textbox max length is 32k characters.

Comment: I agree with @alejandrozuleta. If your textbox is big enough, the only setting that would cut of characters inside it is the **padding**. The only thing to truncate data is if the have a Calculated field on the data set that's TRIMming it or your textbox expression is. I would run the dataset's query from SSMS to see what the actual data is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull up your report in System Management | Reporting | Report Data Definition and check to see if it is a Calculated field limited the number of characters as Hannover Fist has posited. Searching the table Ice.RptCalcField I see a number of out of the box things that limit to x(30), but I don't see anything larger than x(2000). There are couple of DataFields in Ice.ZDataField that are that large, so I am assuming this isn't an out of the box sort of thing.

If the Data Definition field is set to x(16000) try changing it to x(100) and see if that makes a difference. Maybe the value you have is large for the printing framework and it is reverting to some sort of default.

Good luck, I would be interested to see how this turns our for you as we may eventually run into a similar problem.

Comment: I did as you suggested and verified this was not a calculated field. In doing so, the light bulb went off. I checked the query in Report Builder, and saw the expression CAST (T4.ShipComment AS NVARCHAR) AS ShipComment. I had not specified "N", and as I understand, this would default to 30 characters when using the CAST function.